# Where do I find when the next congressional hearing about an issue I'm following is? (e.g. Gamestop)

Tags: united-states, congress

**How do I find out when the next US congressional hearing is regarding ___?**

This is *not* a question for discussing current events surrounding Gamestop and Robinhood.

I expected "when is the next hearing (gamestop OR robinhood)" to tell me exactly that, or at least someone saying that it's not scheduled yet. But 50+ pages of Google results yield no positive answer—and **verbatim**, **Any time**, **Past 24 hours**, and **Past week**, I've tried them all. I know it seems likely it's not scheduled, but it's hard to be sure since results are flooded with news leading up to and about the previous hearing. I can easily imagine all that drowning out newer information.

I've also found comments across several Reddit threads asking this question, but *not a single reply* confirming that it's not yet scheduled. Given the sheer number of users on Reddit, this is strange and IMO indicates that the answer is *not known*, rather than trivial or well-known.

Having figured it out, I'm posting a self-answer with general steps.

Comment: In the past when I've had trouble finding something, a quick e-mail to the office of one of my Congressfolk has resolved it.  Someone in the office can tell you what's happening.  Also, if you come across a news article about a specific issue and they don't mention specifics like meeting dates or bill numbers, e-mail the journalist!  They often forget or don't think to include these details.  Folks asking them for these details often results in them being included in future stories.  (You'll get best results with local news.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**tl;dr - The answer for Gamestop is that it hasn't been scheduled as of Feb 21. Please do not discuss current events here unless relevant to the general question.** Once scheduled, it should be on the congress.gov [Committee Schedule](https://www.congress.gov/committee-schedule).

---

It appears that both Senate and House hearings are only scheduled about 3 to 5 days out from the weekend. I'm sure this makes plenty of logistical sense, but as someone new to U.S. politics and having no idea about committees or how things are run in congress, I'd have just as readily believed that everyday was ad hoc, as I would that there was a full calendar 3 months out and the government's SEO was horrible.

**Official Reference for House *and* Senate**

1. Go to congress.gov's [Committee Schedule](https://www.congress.gov/committee-schedule).
2. Toggle the Expanded view or most of the sessions will be hidden and it's annoying to expand them one at a time:

   [image]
3. Not sure what committee you're looking for? Go through previous weeks (again, in expanded view) until you find the previous hearing. (I could have confused the *House Committee on Financial Services* with the *House Appropriations Subcommittee on Financial Services and General Government* or *Senate Committee on Finance*.) The listings also sometimes list Witnesses that you can search:

   [image]

**Live Updates**

For live updates, subscribe to the committee or chairperson via email, Twitter, etc.

[image]

That's from the [U.S. House Committee on Financial Services](https://financialservices.house.gov/).